# Android, сканирование доступных сетей

Tags: java, android, wifi

Пытаюсь освоить WifiManager.

```
public class ListOfDevices extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextView selection;
    private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
        "sit", "amet",
        "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
        "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
        "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
        "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};
    WifiManager mWifiManager;

    private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_device);

        mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(mWifiScanReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mWifiManager.startScan();


        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items));
        selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
        tv.setText("Проверка");
        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()) {
            tv.append("Wifi is enabled");
        }
        else
        {
            tv.append("Wifi is disabled");
        }

    }
```

Хочу выводить список всех доступных wifi-точек. Статический массив выводится, но возник затык с получением массива доступных wifi.
Не подскажете на данном этапе все ли правильно я сделал?
Напрягает точка с запятой которую меня просит поставить студия в конце BroadcasterReceiver.

Comment: По поводу точки с запятой в конце инициализации BroadcastReceiver не беспокойтесь, ибо она там необходима.

Comment: Пишу в Android Studio. Никак не могу найти как сделать отладку, посмотреть значения переменных в процессе выполнения кода. В visual studio была такая возможность (когда писал на C++)

Comment: в Android Studio точно так же - выставляете брейкпоинты, и запускаете в режиме отладки. Можете еще подключить отладчик прямо "на лету"